# ¿Cómo mostrar los campos de validación de un formulario Asp.Net Mvc desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario el cual usa campos de validación y funciona bien pero ahora agregue un nuevo botón pero este utiliza una llamada Ajax.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que si algún campo obligatorio esta vacío muestre este mensaje de validación que ya tiene asociado o mostrar otro de la misma forma pro desde código JavaScript?

Ahora solo valido que no realice la llamada pero no muestro ningún mensaje de validación.

Ejemplo del formulario:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, "Cart", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "paywithcardform" }))
        {
            <div>
                <div class="mainForm__tit">Datos de Pedido</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuyerIdentification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "mainForm__input", tabindex = 1, maxlength = "150", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Número identificación a facturar" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BuyerIdentification, "", new { @class = "text-danger field-validation-error" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BussinesName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "mainForm__input", tabindex = 1, maxlength = "150", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Nombre comercio a facturar" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BussinesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger field-validation-error" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistributorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "mainForm__input", tabindex = 1, maxlength = "150", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Nombre distribuidor" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistributorName, "", new { @class = "text-danger field-validation-error" })
                </div>
}
```

Mi código en el cliente:

```
function ValidatedFieldPack() {
      var result = true;
       var  buyerIdentification = $('#BuyerIdentification').val();
        var bussinesName = $('#BussinesName').val();
        var distributorName = $('#DistributorName').val();
        if (buyerIdentification === '' || bussinesName === '' || distributorName ===’’) {
            console.log('Autentificado paquete -> Todos los campos requeridos');
            result = false;
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que estás utilizando ASP.Net MVC, es casi un hecho que estás utilizando el **[jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)**, por lo tanto puedes hacer esto:

```
function ValidatedFieldPack() {
  var result = true;
   var  buyerIdentification = $('#BuyerIdentification').val();
    var bussinesName = $('#BussinesName').val();
    var distributorName = $('#DistributorName').val();
    if (buyerIdentification === '' || bussinesName === '' || distributorName ===’’) {
        console.log('Autentificado paquete -> Todos los campos requeridos');
        //Asumo que AQUI es donde necesitas validar tus campos
        $("#NombreDeTuForm").valid(); // <= Agrega esta línea
        result = false;
    }
return result;
```

}